# Go to definition not working on my project (vue & sass file) [visual-studio-code]

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, import, sass, nuxt.js

I am disappointed on two points by developing a Nuxt project on vscode.
On vscode my jsconfig.js is the default one :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "~~/*": ["./*"],
      "@@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".nuxt", "dist"]
}
```

It's working on vue file for autocompletion to import some components for example (with ctrl+space)
But impossible to go to definition next with cmd+click. I do not understand why and this is really annoying.

I can't post image (need 10 reputation), but here is my import on vue file (with no definition found for ...)

```
import PldFooter from '@/components/Footer';
```

Other point, I use sass files on assests folder. Compilation working well but I cannot access by cmd+click to the file from node_modules. Here is an example of import :

```
@import "~bulma/sass/base/helpers.sass";
```

==> No definition found for helpers.sass

Thank you for your help,

Ben.

Answer (score 2):

Have you opened **multiple folders (projects)** in a window?

I'm not sure whether your issue the same as me. I got an issue "Go to Definition not working" in Visual Studio Code when I opened **multiples folders (projects)** and I resolved.

I have used the plugin **Vetur** to support the .vue file.
There are 2 ways which work well:

1. Open **only one project** in a window
2. You can open **multiple projects** in a window but the project you want to "Go to Definition" works well which must be **the first project** in the folder tree in the EXPLORER tab.

It seems the plugin Vetur picks up the first project in multiple projects to be the root folder.

My file **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  ...

  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]

  ...
}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/423#issuecomment-405415204

I apologize if my answer which cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me. My jsconf file was missing the compilerOptions, once I added them, vscode was able to recognize the imports and the constants

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Vetur](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/setup.html#project-setup) setup guide:
If you are using [Webpack's alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) or [TypeScript's path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) to resolve components, **you need to update Vetur's tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json**

**For example:**

```
└── src
    ├── components
    │   ├── a.vue
    │   └── b.vue
    ├── containers
    │   └── index.vue
    ├── index.js
    └── jsconfig.json
```

**jsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "components/*": [
                "src/components/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**index.vue**

```
import a from 'components/a.vue'
import b from 'components/b.vue'
```

It solved the problem in my case.